# can I plot a manipulable 3d graphic?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am a petroleum engineer, I want to plot a wellpath in a 3D graphic if possible, I have the following data: Measured Depth, Inclination, and Azimuth.

Can I plot a 3D fully manipulable graphic on Mathematica?

Comment: Yes you can do this

Comment: can you please tell me how?

Comment: I don’t know what you want to do, what have you attempted so far? Perhaps you can try to make a `Graphics3D`object of what you want based on the parameters you have then wrap that in `Manipulate` or use something like some `Dynamic` wrappers if you have problems. I suggest searching on this site a bit as this has been answered a great number of times. If you can provide some code and a small bit of context, it will be a lot better for others to help you.

Comment: Here’s a good example https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101676/63039 follow those tags and see what you can do :)

Comment: Why don't you use AutoCAD's drawing function?

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes how do you use that in Mathematica? ;) (you export/import the file-type you use!)